# How to use pqxx::stateless_cursor class from libpqxx?

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I'm learning libpqxx, the C++ API to PostgreSQL.  I'd like to use the pqxx::stateless_cursor class, but 1) I find the Doxygen output unhelpful in this case, and 2) the pqxx.org website has been down for some time now.

Anyone know how to use it?

I believe this is how I construct one:

```
pqxx::stateless_cursor <pqxx::cursor_base::read_only, pqxx::cursor_base::owned>
    cursor( work, "SELECT * FROM mytable", ?, ? );
```

The last two parms are called `cname` and `hold`, but are not documented.

And once the cursor is created, how would I go about using it in a for() loop to get each row, one at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Eelke for the comments on `cname` and `hold`.

I figured out how to make pqxx::stateless_cursor work.  I have no idea if there is a cleaner or more obvious way but here is an example:

```
pqxx::work work( conn );
pqxx::stateless_cursor<pqxx::cursor_base::read_only, pqxx::cursor_base::owned>
    cursor( work, "SELECT * FROM mytable", "mycursor", false );

for ( size_t idx = 0; true; idx ++ )
{
    pqxx::result result = cursor.retrieve( idx, idx + 1 );
    if ( result.empty() )
    {
        // nothing left to read
        break;
    }

    // Do something with "result" which contains a single
    // row in this example since we told the cursor to
    // retrieve row #idx (inclusive) to idx+1 (exclusive).
    std::cout << result[ 0 ][ "name" ].as<std::string>() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the pqxx library but based on the underlying DECLARE command of postgresql I would guess

That cname is the name of the cursor, so it can be anything postgresql normally accepts as a cursor name.

That hold refers to the WITH HOLD option of a cursor, from the docs:

> WITH HOLD specifies that the cursor can continue to be used after the
>   transaction that created it successfully commits. WITHOUT HOLD
>   specifies that the cursor cannot be used outside of the transaction
>   that created it. If neither WITHOUT HOLD nor WITH HOLD is specified,
>   WITHOUT HOLD is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another cursor example, using a do-while() loop:

```
     const std::conStr("user=" + opt::dbUser + " password=" + opt::dbPasswd + " host=" + opt::dbHost + " dbname=" + opt::dbName);                                            

      pqxx::connection conn(connStr);
      pqxx::work txn(conn);
      std::string selectString = "SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE condition";

      pqxx::stateless_cursor<pqxx::cursor_base::read_only, pqxx::cursor_base::owned> 
      cursor(txn, selectString, "myCursor", false);

      //cursor variables
      size_t idx = 0;       //starting location
      size_t step = 10000;  //number of rows for each chunk
      pqxx::result result;
      do{
        //get next cursor chunk and update the index
        result = cursor.retrieve( idx, idx + step );
        idx += step;

        size_t records = result.size();
        cout << idx << ": records pulled = " << records << endl;

        for( pqxx::result::const_iterator row : result ){
          //iterate over cursor rows
        }
      }
      while( result.size() == step ); //if the result.size() != step, we're on our last loop
      cout << "Done!" << endl;
```